# VHDL assign integer indexed vector to enum indexed vector

Tags: arrays, vhdl, enumerated-types

does anyone know if this is legal in VHDL?

```
type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
signal fooArray is array (foo'left to foo'right) of int;
signal intArray is array (0 to 2) of int;

fooArray <= intArray;   -- is this statement legal?
```

as far as i can tell reading the VHDL LRM, array assignment is done by position, not by index. so i know that assigning arrays who's bounds are not equal but whose index lengths are equal is legal. but there is nothing that talks about assigning an array indexed by integers to an array indexed by an enumerated type. just wondering if anyone knows if this is legal or if the dominant VHDL simulators allow this?

okay, i guess i should have indicated that the code was "pseudo-code" (and my vhdl coding sucks!). my main intent is to find out if VHDL allows the assignment of an array indexed by enum's to an array of the same size indexed by integers. so let's try this example:

```
entity eiv is
end entity;

architecture fooArch of eiv is

    type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
    type fooArrayType is array(foo) of integer;
    type intArrayType is array(0 to 2) of integer;

    signal fooArray : fooArrayType;
    signal intArray : intArrayType;

begin

Statement:
    fooArray <= intArray;   -- is this statement legal?

end architecture;
```

Comment: Less complicated : `type fooArray is array(foo) of int;` For the actual problems see David's answer.

Comment: The `fooArray <= intArray` is not possible, since the declaration of `fooArray` and `intArray` need to be based on different types if the index are to be from `foo` and from `integer`, and the strong typed nature of VHDL makes assign from one type to another illegal, even for same number and type of elements.  Details in David's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code snippet doesn't represent legal VHDL.

These three attempts form a narrative:

```
entity eiv is
end entity;

architecture foo of eiv is

    type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
    signal fooArray is array (foo'left to foo'right) of int;
    signal intArray is array (0 to 2) of int;

begin

Statement:
    fooArray <= intArray;   -- is this statement legal?

end architecture;
```

> %% ghdl -a eiv.vhdl
>   eiv.vhdl:8:21: ',' or ':' is expected after identifier in signal declaration
>   ghdl: compilation error
>   %%

So we get rid of the glaring syntax errors:

```
entity eiv is
end entity;

architecture foo of eiv is

    type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
    type int_array is array (natural range <>) of integer;
    signal fooArray: int_array (foo'left to foo'right);
    signal intArray: int_array (0 to 2);

begin

Statement:
    fooArray <= intArray;   -- is this statement legal?

end architecture;
```

> %% ghdl -a eiv.vhdl
>   eiv.vhdl:9:49: can't match 'right attribute with type integer
>   eiv.vhdl:9:49: (location of 'right attribute)
>   eiv.vhdl:9:37: can't match 'left attribute with type integer
>   eiv.vhdl:9:37: (location of 'left attribute)
>   eiv.vhdl:15:17: length of value does not match length of target
>   ghdl: compilation error
>   %%

So off to look up **Predefined attributes** in the LRM:

```
entity eiv is
end entity;

architecture foo of eiv is

    type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
    type int_array is array (natural range <>) of integer;
    signal fooArray: int_array (foo'POS(ONE) to foo'POS(THREE));
    signal intArray: int_array (0 to 2);

begin

Statement:
    fooArray <= intArray;   -- is this statement legal?

end architecture;
```

> %% ghdl -a eiv.vhdl    # analyze
>   %% ghdl -e eiv         # elaborate
>   %% ghdl -r eiv         # run
>   %%

And the reason why we have to change attributes is because the value returned by `foo'RIGHT and foo'LEFT` is `ONE` and `THREE` and not a position index.

Take the character type, whose values we are familiar with `A`, `B`, `C`,...  The position indexes for those would be 65, 66, 67,...  (Instead of writing a VHDL design description to determine this I looked at the man page for ascii, you'll note in package standard `character` follows ASCII through position 127).

So can you extract the position indexes from a type enumeration array?  Yes.

Can you use the enumeration value as an array bound directly?  No.

Position and value are separate.  You can recover the position using the `'POS` attribute.

Alternately `int_array (foo'POS(foo'LEFT) to foo'POS(foo'RIGHT))` instead of specifying the values directly.

### clarified source:

> okay, i guess i should have indicated that the code was "pseudo-code"
>   (and my vhdl coding sucks!). my main intent is to find out if VHDL
>   allows the assignment of an array indexed by enum's to an array of the
>   same size indexed by integers. so let's try this example:

```
entity eiv is
end entity;

architecture fooArch of eiv is

    type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
    type fooArrayType is array(foo) of integer;
    type intArrayType is array(0 to 2) of integer;

    signal fooArray : fooArrayType;
    signal intArray : intArrayType;

begin

Statement:
    fooArray <= intArray;   -- is this statement legal?

end architecture;
```

The short answer is No, the statement isn't legal.  Type `foo` isn't an integer subtype, making `FooArrayType` incompatible with `IntArrayType`.

Notice

```
fooArray <= fooArrayType(intArray);
```

won't work either.  They aren't closely related types. You'd need a function to type convert `intArray` to `fooArrayType`:

```
entity eiv1 is
end entity;

architecture fooArch of eiv1 is

    type foo is (ONE, TWO, THREE);
    type fooArrayType is array(foo) of integer;
    type intArrayType is array(0 to 2) of integer;

    signal fooArray : fooArrayType;
    signal intArray : intArrayType;

    function conv_fooarray (v: intArrayType) return fooArrayType is
        variable temp:  fooArrayType;
    begin
        for i in v'range loop
            temp(foo'VAL(i))  := v(i);
        end loop;
        return temp;
    end function;

begin
Statement:
    fooArray <= conv_fooarray(intArray);   -- this statement is legal

end architecture;
```

Comment: i have to apologize for such crappy vhdl coding. i've edited my main question to try to clarify what i'm trying to find out. i want to know if you can assign an array indexed by an enumeration to an array of the same size that is indexed by integers. i hope my new code makes this clearer and hopefully you can answer this.